Text disappearing in MiKTeX
This is about a hard-to-reproduce problem that has plagued me intermittently for years.  I reported it earlier, but to no avail.  I was now finally able to boil it down to a very small test case and I thought it would be better to make this a new question.  Here's my MWE:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paperwidth=127mm,paperheight=203mm,totalwidth=92mm,totalheight=174mm,
  includehead,includefoot,marginparwidth=0mm,marginparsep=0mm,
  headheight=0mm,headsep=0mm,footskip=9mm,hcentering,heightrounded
}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{{\tiny{\sffamily\textls[150]{\MakeUppercase{Gesichter der Mathematik}}}\rule[-1.6\dp\strutbox]{.3pt}{1.4\baselineskip}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand\mytext{%
Erst im 20. Jahrhundert kam die volle Wahrheit ans Licht.  Die Inhalte des
Buches stammten tatsächlich von Johann, der gute didaktische Aufbau war jedoch
das Werk L'Hospitals.  Hinter der Sache stand ein Arrangement, demzufolge
Bernoulli für seine Mathematik bezahlt wurde und im Gegenzug zustimmte, seine
Ergebnisse nicht selbst zu publizieren.  Der junge Bernoulli hatte sich quasi
verkauft und das später bereut.

}

\begin{document}
\section*{Whatever}\label{whatever}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Whatever}

\mytext
\mytext
\mytext
\mytext
\mytext
\mytext
\mytext
\end{document}

I'm on Windows 10 with MikTeX updated today (but the problem has been there for years).  If I compile this file from TeXWorks with the pdfLaTeX option, everything is fine.  If I compile it from a console window with pdflatex test.tex, the first line of the last paragraph is incomplete - see image below.  (pdflatex test.tex on Ubuntu Linux (running in WSL) works fine.)

To provoke the error in my MWE, the amsmath package must be present although it is not used.  Also, the \textsl command in the footer seems to be necessary.  The whole MWE is very fragile: change one bit and the error is gone.
FWIW, below are the differences between the two runs as reported by the log files.  (I noticed that TeXWorks calls miktex-pdftex.exe instead of pdflatex.exe.  But if there is a program called pdflatex.exe, shouldn't it work as expected?)  What is happening here?
--- pdflatex.log    2024-04-05 22:23:22.784217000 +0200
+++ texWorks.log    2024-04-05 22:20:31.551568000 +0200
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.3.31) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.4.5)  5 APR 2024 22:23
+This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.3.31) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.4.5)  5 APR 2024 22:20
 entering extended mode
  restricted \write18 enabled.
  %&-line parsing enabled.
@@ -367,16 +367,16 @@
  ) 
 Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
  6262 strings out of 474400
- 106989 string characters out of 4507339
- 3925496 words of memory out of 8000000
+ 106989 string characters out of 5757339
+ 1932496 words of memory out of 6000000
  28534 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
- 592261 words of font info for 70 fonts, out of 2000000 for 9000
+ 592261 words of font info for 70 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
  65i,12n,69p,1003b,446s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
 <E:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/libertinus-type1/LibertinusSans-Regular.pfb><E:
 /MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/libertinus-type1/LibertinusSerif-Bold.pfb><E:/MikTeX
 /fonts/type1/public/libertinus-type1/LibertinusSerif-Regular.pfb>
-Output written on test.pdf (2 pages, 261653 bytes).
+Output written on test.pdf (2 pages, 261644 bytes).
 PDF statistics:
  27 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)

[Update 2024-04-06] I've put the code (with the suggested debugging line) and the uncompressed PDF files at https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ksld8e2db09m39evjncg1/MWE.zip?rlkey=61d9avkrpghs6ecmq6gp9b64o&dl=0
If I compare the two PDF files, the main difference seems to be the following (where the first line is from the correct output):
[(Erst)-250(im)-250(20.)-250(Jahrhundert)-250(kam)-250(die)-250(v)8(olle)-250(W)60(ahrheit)-250(ans)-250(Licht.)-250(Die)]

[(Erst)]TJ -32626.8 0 Td [(im)-250(20.)-250(Jahrhundert)-250(kam)-250(die)-250(v)8(olle)-250(W)60(ahrheit)-250(ans)-250(Licht.)-250(Die)]

The first one was compiled using miktex-pdftex.exe -undump=pdflatex test.tex, the second one with pdflatex.exe test.tex.  TeXWorks was not involved.  (I'm mentioning this because some people misunderstood me and thought this was about an issue with TeXWorks.  This is about a bug in the MiKTeX distribution of pdflatex as far as I understand it.)
[Second update from 2024-04-06] Digging through my old e-mails, maybe I found the culprit.  Years ago, I did this (following some advice from someone I forgot):
initexmf --edit-config-file pdflatex

Add this to the file and save it:
pool_size=5000000
main_memory=6000000
extra_mem_bot=2000000
font_mem_size=2000000

Then run this:
initexmf --dump=pdflatex

With these settings, I get the error.  If I repeat the process with an empty config file, the error is gone.

are you using the same viewer, are you sure the text really isn't there, rather than a viewer bug making it vanish?

can you make the two pdf available somewhere (gdrive or dropbox or something similar)?

For what it's worth, I still have an unresolved MikTex (TexWorks) viewer bug: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597749/scalebox-error-on-pdf-images. It views OK on Adobe, just not on TeXworks.

the pdflatex log is made with a different sizes for all the fixed size arrays, so probably a different format

@DavidCarlisle It's not a viewer bug.  The line is missing in SumatraPDF as well as Acrobat Reader.  I noticed the different sizes as well.  But what exactly does "different format" mean?

@DavidCarlisle The two PDF files are now in a ZIP archive at http://weitz.de/files/MWE.zip

thanks (I can't download them over http due to firewall security) but I don't have miktex anyway but other miktex users should be able to confirm. Hower it looks like a difference between miktex-pdftex and pdftex binaries (both distributed by miktex) I doubt texworks is involved. The miktex maintainer isn't usually here you should report at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/

could you add \ExplSyntaxOn\sys_ensure_backend:\pdf_uncompress:\ExplSyntaxOff as first line and recompile, then the pdfs are uncompressed and easier to check.

@UlrikeFischer I've added some more information and a DropBox download link to the question.

I've now also reported this to the MiKTeX maintainers: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1474

well you saw the diff in the pdf, that is the same as in your older question. And as @DavidCarlisle already mentioned you obviously use different format files. Find the log of the format creations, they should be in an folder like ....\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\makefmt\pdflatex with date and compare them.

@UlrikeFischer I will do that.  But I somehow can't brush off the feeling that all replies amount to: "This is your fault".  Even if I use different format files, can't we agree that pdflatex shouldn't produce a PDF with missing text?

no the replies are not "it's your fault" but rather "please provide more detailed information as we can't reproduce" (in my case not surprising as I don't have miktex) it may depend on the exact build of miktex you have or the exact hardware you are running on or anything..  so as much information as possible would be good.

The folder pdflatex contains 11 log files going back to 2021, probably related to MiKTeX updates.  I don't know enough about the inner workings of TeX to understand what I should look for, but I've put all of them here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9to7j8qtf3dpywbm89f78/mkfmtlogs.zip?rlkey=164txo7l7o1dspfrt19k8mhzu&dl=0

I've added more information about the setup to the question.
